# Cannot resolve org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.33 in IntelliJ when creating spring initializr project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, oracle10g

I am new to SpringBoot.It was working fine earlier with Oracle DB.Now When i create new Spring Inializr Project with data-jpa and OracleDriver..it shows cannot resolve.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tly3N.jpg)
.when i run the project, it shows error like this

```
020-03-27 16:21:22.756  INFO 11812 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on LAPTOP-KCGVKNJ8 with PID 11812 (C:\Users\SAHANA\IdeaProjects\demoTestOpnOrac\target\classes started by SAHANA in C:\Users\SAHANA\IdeaProjects\demoTestOpnOrac)

2020-03-27 16:21:22.759  INFO 11812 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

2020-03-27 16:21:23.737  INFO 11812 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.

2020-03-27 16:21:23.784  INFO 11812 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 25ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.

2020-03-27 16:21:24.366  INFO 11812 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-27 16:21:24.424  INFO 11812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version              
      : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-03-27 16:21:24.508  INFO 11812 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-27 16:21:24.578  INFO 11812 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-27 16:21:24.981  INFO 11812 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource 
      : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-27 16:21:24.995  INFO 11812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2020-03-27 16:21:25.328  INFO 11812 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]

2020-03-27 16:21:25.334  INFO 11812 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

2020-03-27 16:21:25.475  INFO 11812 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 3.059 seconds (JVM running for 3.919)

2020-03-27 16:21:25.479  INFO 11812 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

2020-03-27 16:21:25.481  INFO 11812 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
e
2020-03-27 16:21:25.491  INFO 11812 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? Show it fully here. Do you have internet connection? Have you tried to run it from command line by Gradle?

Comment: When i newly create a project ...Error like Cannot resolve org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.33  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tly3N.jpg

Comment: Sound like you have network issue. Have you tried to build it from command line?

Comment: It was because of invalid classes root..Now it is solved by manually replacing version 2.2.6.RELEASE of spring-boot-starter-parent with 2.2.5.RELEASE in pom.xml                Thankyou!